# Adjust / stretch image size to fit div class css

Tags: html, css

I want to adjust / stretch my image that it completly fits the size of my div class.
I tried background-size: cover but then the image just scales to the size of my div class and half of the image is not visible.
I also tried object-fit: fill but it didnt work for me.
Does anyone have an Idea to fix my problem?

[div class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Dfl.png)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dqvP.png)

Comment: Try `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Comment: Nice! Seems to work. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

use object-fit : cover this make image resolution fill

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_object-fit_without